# As from an array of fields, you can save the entered values?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the value from inpit and store it. I create an array in which I put the selected number of "input", then iterate over the array and output the data. The task is to get the entered value into all "inputs" and save them. Tried using "e.target", the solution didn't help. Tell me how you can implement it?

```
class Rules extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
            newNameColumns: [],
           
        }
    };
    
    handleChange(value) {
        let newInputColumns = []
        for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            newInputColumns.push({
                key: this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1}),
                input: <Input />
            });

        }
        this.setState({newNameColumns: [...this.state.newNameColumns, ...newInputColumns]});
    }

    render() {
     
        const {newNameColumns} = this.state;

        const dataTableRules =
            <div className="modal-create-table">
                <Input placeholder="enter title rule"/>
                <Select defaultValue="0" style={{width: 220}} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                    <Option value="1">1</Option>
                    <Option value="2">2</Option>
                    <Option value="3">3</Option>
                    <Option value="4">4</Option>
                </Select>
            </div>;

        return (
            <div className="rules">
                
                <TableRules/>
                <Modal
                   
                    newNameColumns={newNameColumns}
                 
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
{props.newNameColumns.map(item => (
                        <div className="new-input-columns-name" key={item.key}>{item.input}</div>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `event.target.value` in change handler.

```
handleChange(event) {
   ...

   this.setState({tableAmountColumns: event.target.value});

   ...
}
```

Comment: I have an "input" array, the values ​​will overwrite each other

Comment: Can you include where you invoke handleChange and more context of the component(s)

Comment: I updated the code, indicated the main component and the one where I pass props

Comment: two things to consider: 1. I see you might be using a custom <Select> and <Option> component rather than vanilla <select> and <option>. If its all the same to you maybe change these to vanilla, or otherwise look to what prop(s) the custom Select is expecting. The vanilla components worked fine when accessing e.target.value 2. If you resolve part 1, you'll likely still have issues attempting to set the keys on newInputColumn objs using setState. There are multiple issues with this, not the least of which is that setState does not return a value.